# Keeping many fsockopen connections open at a time

Tags: php, fsockopen, connection

I'm building a php-based website for people who run game servers for a certain online video game. In order to access the in-game chat as it happens, I connect to their server using fsockopen(), set the stream_set_timeout() to something fairly long, and then just use fread in a conditional loop: `while($string = fread($socket, 4))`, collecting the chat message, and flushing the buffer so it gets output on screen instantly.

This all works extremely well so far, but since this website will be used by potentially hundreds of game servers, I am not totally sure this is scalable. Is it feasible to have hundreds of fsockopen connections open to different servers at any given time? It doesn't seem to use a lot of bandwidth while the connection is open-but-dormant, but I don't know enough about socket connections to know for sure what performance issues I might run into.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: You might run into a file descriptor limit.

Comment: Thanks for providing the jumping off point for more research.

So as long as the total number of connections is below that limit, there's no major bandwidth or other resource issues I should be aware of, even with a thousand simultaneous sockets open?

Comment: That's not what I stated, otherwise I would have made an answer out of it.

Comment: Indeed, and I was just asking to see if I could get a tad more info outta ya. Thanks either way :)